# Битовые операции

Tags: битовые-операции

```
String binary[] = {
"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
"1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
};
int a = 3; // 0 + 2 + 1 или 0011 в двоичном представлении
int b = 6; // 4 + 2 + 0 или 0110 в двоичном представлении
int c = a | b;
int d = a & b;
int e = a ^ b;
int f = (~a & b) | (a & ~b);
int g = ~a & 0x0f;
System.out.println(" a = " + binary[a]);
System.out.println(" b = " + binary[b]);
System.out.println(" a|b = " + binary[c]);
System.out.println(" a&b = " + binary[d]);
System.out.println(" a^b = " + binary[e]);
System.out.println("~a&b|a&~b = " + binary[f]);
System.out.println(" ~a = " + binary[g]);
}
}
```

На экран выводит

```
b = 0110
a|b = 0111
a&b = 0010
a^b = 0101
~a&b|a&~b = 0101
~a = 1100
```

Почему, когда убираю из `(int g)` строку `(& 0x0f)`, компилятор при выводе выдает ошибку, если `~a` равно 15, что не выходит за пределы  массива строк?

Comment: @sfisher121212, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Потому что инвертирование переворачивает все биты, а не только последние 4, как Вы надеетесь. То есть все 32.

Так как левый бит равен 1 (после инвертирования), то это будет отрицательное число. А это точно не может быть индексом массива.